# How to write left join with where clause using JPQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm having an issue with writing inner left join with JPQL.
I have two tables:

- Desk
- Reservation

Desk has one to many relation with Reservation.
On Reservation table I have a column with a date.

Now, what I want to achieve is:
I want to write a query that will find all desks that have no reservation for a given date, so it means that I want to have **desks that do not have any reservations at all**, and **desks that have reservations as long as none of them is for a given date**.

The queries that I have tried so far:

1.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT desk FROM Desk desk left join desk.reservations reservation ON reservation.date <> :date"
Page<Desk> findDesks(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

2. 

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT desk FROM Desk desk left join desk.reservations reservation WHERE (desk.reservations is null or reservation.date <> :date)")
Page<Desk> findDesks(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

3. 

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT desk FROM Desk desk left join desk.reservations reservation WHERE reservation.date <> :date")
Page<Desk> findDesks(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

When I try this query, I'm getting only desks that have some reservations where none of the reservation is for a given date, but I'm not receiving those desks that have no reservations at all.
Could someone tell me how should I change my query, so I could find all desks where there is no related reservation for a given date?

Comment: How are the 2 tables related?

Comment: It's a one-to-many relationship. So 1 Desk may be related to many Reservations

Comment: And this relationship is based on which columns? Your joins seem to miss them.

Comment: @forpas 
I tried it this way already as well:

`@Query("SELECT DISTINCT desk FROM Desk desk left join desk.reservations reservation ON reservation.desk.id = desk.id WHERE reservation.date <> :date")`

but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself :)

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT desk FROM Desk desk left join desk.reservations 
reservation ON reservation.desk.id = desk.id WHERE desk.reservations IS 
EMPTY OR :date <> ALL(SELECT date from reservation)")
```

So the key to solve it, was to use IS EMPTY to make sure that I'm finding desks that have no reservation at all, and also using ALL operator to filter out the desks that have any reservation for a given date.